# Schroedinger's object?

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

I tried to check, if an object (or layer) does exist in a document.
This script works, if there is a pageItem with name x. But it fails if not. (so far so good)

The strange part is: even if this object named "x" doesn't exist, A returns an object. If I'm asking it for its name, id, index or anything the script stops because of an error.

```
//Schroedinger's object
A=app.activeDocument.pageItems.itemByName("x")
$.writeln(A) //returns: [object PageItem]
$.writeln(A.id) //Error. doesn't exist
```

So please try it out with a blank new document in InDesign and run the script. I don't understand this phenomenon.

At least you can verify it's existance with A.isValid (that's what I am using now, hoping for the best)

Comment: [This blog post](http://www.indiscripts.com/post/2010/06/on-everyitem-part-1) explains things helpfully.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is correct.

`.itemByName()` always returns a `PageItem` object (provided that you passed some string as the argument). But the returned object will only be valid if a corresponding item exists in the document. You should use the `.isValid` property to verify whether the returned object is valid.